# Where is Add Product Click Button of magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, product-list, products-management

I want to know place of "Add Product" of magento on Manage products page. And also the function which is work onclick of that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

if you talking about the this `Add product` and function.

```
 onclick="setLocation('http://10.10.10.77/magento/index.php/admin/catalog_product/new/key/1643752047c44a89d5034754bd42a40f/')"
```

this is simple function to redirect the page that are defined in `js/varien/js.js` on line `30.`

```
function setLocation(url){
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: I want to pass some more parameters in location for my extension. How can i pass that parameter. I find _prepareLayout function and here "'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/*/new')}')"," this line is written.

Comment: "'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/*/new').?param=param}')" simplae way to do it

Comment: It opens add product page, for security reason if user manaually remove that parameter from url and hit page then i want location redirect with my parameters.

Comment: if you want to put for  security purpose  then pass with in session. url parameter is never secure. it is easily accessible. or you can encode the value it's up to you.

Comment: Ok, so as you check in your image "Choose Store View" select box. I want to get that value in my session on other page how can i do that.

Comment: you can use ajax request  on  onchange function  to create the session.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30574/discussion-between-mathew-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: template/store/switcher.phtml

Comment: This works but it add to cart url append with base url like :          `http:/example.com/ http://example.com/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3RoZXdvbWVuLm5leHRtcC5uZXQv/product/2/form_key/Vb3Tx0y9HODW8LYC/`   any suggestion   ?